# Is it sufficient to use only catalina-ws.jar to have a REST webservice in Tomcat7?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I came across many tutorials using Jersey and Tomcat7 to implement rest web services. But I also see that tomcat provides web services support if you download  catalina-ws.jar (look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/extras.html)). So I would like to ask if we can use only this jar in the project and call rest web services ? Has anyone used this before ?

Comment: that page says that it only provides support for JSR 109, which has nothing to do with REST

Comment: I got confused with Rest services and the jar that tomcat was offering, so wanted to know if that jar can be used to implement Rest services. SO I guess the answer is NO for that.

Answer (score 2):

Jersey is JAX-RS ([JSR-311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)) which is absolutely not the same as WebServices 1.2 ([JSR-109](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=109)), which is part of [Java EE 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_5_.28May_11.2C_2006.29). Either install [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) separately, or replace Tomcat by [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/). You only get [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) instead of Jersey.

Comment: A nice perk as well is you get full (at)Inject support and full (at)PersistenceContext and all the other injection support in your RESTful services with TomEE.