# WAR failed to deploy

Tags: java, web-services, maven, netbeans

I have a Maven JEE application running fine in TomEE. I created a SOAP Web Service in Netbeans: `New - Web Service`, which creates a simple "hello" service. For some reason I get a message

[image]

> The web server you have selected does not seem to support JSR 109
>   specification. To enable the web server to process annotated web
>   services, the sun-jaxws.xml file should be created and servlets
>   entries for web services need to be generated in web.xml file

I accept, clean, build... No matter what I do, I always get this message every single time I open Netbeans. Like the changes were not persistent.

Then the main problem is when I try to run the project. I get a long list of errors

**In server log**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomee.catalina.JavaeeInstanceManager
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
```

**In the logs**

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceTest]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null
    at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:234)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.readWsdl(WsDeployer.java:451)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceTest]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:291)
....
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceTest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
....
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1270)
....
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null
    at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:234)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.readWsdl(WsDeployer.java:451)
....
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache-Tomee-jaxrs-1.7.4\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebServiceTest.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceTest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
....
```

---

**EDIT**

I have added these dependencies but still getting the same errors when building/running

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ws -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ws</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Besides the Maven dependencies, I have manually copied the files `jaxrpc-api-1.1.jar` and `tomcat-catalina-ws-7.0.5.jar` in the TomEE lib folder. The file `wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar` already existed. I restarted Netbeans. Not sure these are the needed jars, but they do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because Tomcat is not JSR-109 compliant out of the box.  I discovered this in the Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/extras.html#Web_Services_support_(JSR_109)) which may help you:

> ### Web Services support (JSR 109)
>
> Tomcat provides factories for JSR 109 which may be used to resolve web services references. Place the generated catalina-ws.jar as well as jaxrpc.jar and wsdl4j.jar (or another implementation of JSR 109) in the Tomcat lib folder.
>
> Users should be aware that wsdl4j.jar is licensed under CPL 1.0 and not the Apache License version 2.0.

Comment: Thanks!  That is promising and I will try now to find the JARs on Maven. Although I am using TomEE and, if I am not mistaken, it seems it should work as BalusC says here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633343/is-it-sufficient-to-use-only-catalina-ws-jar-to-have-a-rest-webservice-in-tomcat

Comment: Check your Tomcat lib folder to make sure the JARs are in there.  Yes, I agree with BalusC that it should work.  Maybe this will lead down a path towards finding the actual solution.

Comment: I did but doesn't seem to work (see my edit). I also installed the latest TomEE 7 plumee (released in May) and still have the same problem. Would it have something to do with TomEE using CXF being different from the Web Services that Netbeans creates?

Comment: I am not sure.  I will leave this up for the time being because it may help someone else reading your question.  I will delete later.

Comment: Yes, please, don't delete yet. It is helpful to find possible sources of error

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure why this error happened... As Tim said, Tomcat might not be JSR-109 compliant out of the box (see his post) but since I am using TomEE, it should be OK. After many tests, I saw that using this `nb-configuration.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-shared-configuration>
    <!--
    This file contains additional configuration written by modules in the NetBeans IDE.
    The configuration is intended to be shared among all the users of project and
    therefore it is assumed to be part of version control checkout.
    Without this configuration present, some functionality in the IDE may be limited or fail altogether.
    -->
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <!--
        Properties that influence various parts of the IDE, especially code formatting and the like. 
        You can copy and paste the single properties, into the pom.xml file and the IDE will pick them up.
        That way multiple projects can share the same settings (useful for formatting rules for example).
        Any value defined here will override the pom.xml file value but is only applicable to the current project.
        -->
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>1.7-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>Tomcat</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.generate_5f_nonjsr109>false</org-netbeans-modules-maven-jaxws.generate_5f_nonjsr109>
        <netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>JDK_1.8</netbeans.hint.jdkPlatform>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```

Was helping [at least] to tell Netbeans not to raise the message (I believe). Then with usual Web Services annotation (`@WebService(serviceName = "...")`, `@WebMethod(operationName = "...")`, `@WebResult(name = "...")`...) and after some server restarts and making sure the `context.xml` was valid, the Web Services deployed. I hope it helps people with the same problem.