# org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null

Tags: java, apache-tomee, tomee-7, netbeans-12

I am using NetBeans 12 and apache-tomee-plume-7.0.9. I have deployed a project from Tomee manager app and put necessary jar files under `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the deployed project. Previously I was getting this error

```java
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.Navigator.isSameType(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.hasFactoryConstructor(ClassInfoImpl.java:1318)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:208)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:114)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JAXBContextFactory.newInstance(JAXBContextFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.getContext(JaxbJavaee.java:88)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:102)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.readBeans(ReadDescriptors.java:682)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.mergeBeansXml(DeploymentLoader.java:1190)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addBeansXmls(DeploymentLoader.java:1178)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:1094)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:819)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:230)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2334)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1192)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
```

This is resolved by creating a folder "endorsed" under CATALINA_HOME and copying jaxb-*.jar(s). I found this solution in this link: https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/issues/7#issuecomment-383578127

Now the log shows that the ejbs are being deployed but getting new issues:

```java
org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ba.jee-war]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:234) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.deploy(WsDeployer.java:72) at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1037) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281) at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.readWsdl(WsDeployer.java:450) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.getWsdl(WsDeployer.java:426) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:209) ... 19 more 08-Sep-2022 11:00:35.026 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ba.jee-war]] in state [STARTING_PREP] 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:845) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1631) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1312) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 08-Sep-2022 11:00:35.027 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ba.jee-war]] 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1315) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ... 10 more Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl: null 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:234) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.deploy(WsDeployer.java:72) at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1037) 
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281) ... 15 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.readWsdl(WsDeployer.java:450) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.getWsdl(WsDeployer.java:426) 
at org.apache.openejb.config.WsDeployer.processPorts(WsDeployer.java:209) ... 19 more 08-Sep-2022 11:00:35.027 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application archive [/Applications/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.9/webapps/ba.jee-war.war] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ba.jee-war]] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: At the very end of your question there is a stack trace which is printed on a single line, which makes it impossible to read. It is also preceded by some text which should be distinct from the first stack trace. Please fix the formatting in your question because as it stands it is very hard to understand.

Comment: Also, since you are getting the message _"Unable to load servlet class: com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl"_ in the second stack trace, it would be helpful if you explicitly listed the jars you added to **/WEB-INF/lib**. Just stating that you _"put necessary jar files under /WEB-INF/lib folder of the deployed project"_ is not detailed enough. Also, does the old question [WAR failed to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37965492/2985643) help? It describes to the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I followed the solution in old question -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37965492/2985643, but it's not working. This is the link for the list of jar files in /WEB-INF/lib folder: https://bsnappscom-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/personal/mhossain_bsnapps_com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B3aaab5aa-fbcb-4809-a2f2-3452f89fa90a%7D&action=default

Answer (score 0):

the issue resolved by removing Metro related jar files - webservices-extra.jar, webservices-rt.jar, webservices-tools.jar, webservices-api.jar, webservices-extra-api.jar from WEB-INF/lib folder.

May be there is a conflict between theses and the jar for Apache web services.